# iCloud dashboard: Cannot deploy CloudKit schema to Production

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I have a released app with an existing production schema. I made changes to the development schema and now I want to deploy to production.

After clicking `Deploy Schema to Production...`, the popup dialog says `There was a problem loading the environment's status`. js console shows the server responded with an HTTP 500. I tried a lot of times this morning and has been the same each time.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Contact Apple, Inc.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error. Must be a problem on Apple's end.

Comment: I'm getting the same. It's been happening for a day and a half. Guess we need to wait for Apple engineer to return to the "office" after the weekend.

Comment: same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879420/does-icloud-need-to-be-in-the-production-environment-in-order-to-use-in-producti

Comment: Tried again and it is now working. Guessing Apple fixed on their end.