# Does iCloud need to be in the Production environment in order to use in Production?

Tags: ios, xcode, schema, icloud, cloudkit

I added Cloudkit support to my iOS and WatchOS App, but I cannot deploy my schema to production due to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855311/icloud-dashboard-cannot-deploy-cloudkit-schema-to-production): [image] Do I need to wait until this is fixed so I can deploy to Production or can I ship and still be in Development mode on the console?

I've also read that I can edit my plist to switch to development mode but I am not seeing that option in my Entitlements: [image]

Update: July 13 6pm EST no longer getting the error message but now it acts as if it is going to deploy but when I hit cancel and refresh it isn't deployed ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, you need CloudKit in production to use it in your production app.  You may be able to release your app if it handles unavailable CloudKit gracefully.